# My name was displayed incorrectly, but fixed on refresh

Tags: discussion

I was shocked to see my name displayed incorrectly on an answer:

[image: wrong]

---

After 2 refreshes, it was back to normal:

[image: correct]

Is this a bug? Or was it a temporary glitch?

Comment: Did you recently change your username..?

Comment: No. Its been the same from the beginning.

Comment: It might be a problem with your browser. *En français,* the word "an(s)" means "year(s)" so it looks like it could be an automatic translation of a similar language.

Comment: @Laurel ok.. but that has never happened before and why did the order change if it was a translation?

Comment: @AniMenon Many languages put words in different orders. If it grabbed "Ani Menon" as something to be translated, it's very reasonable that the words would end up in a different order *after* translation. It's kinda up in the air what a translator will do with words it doesn't translate.

Comment: @animuson ok.. I haven't seen that before for any Latin language. But its possible.

Comment: What's this automatic translation everyone is talking about?  I don't recall any browser performing completely automatic translations of selected words only without any notice.  And there's no indication that the op is using a translation service.

Comment: @davidism: Chrome has done so for yonks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit huh, I thought it just put a bar at the top asking if you wanted a translation.

Comment: @davidism: We can't rule out the OP having clicked on the button in that pop-up accidentally.

Comment: Interesting to note that if you (in Chrome) right click and choose "Translate to English", [it performs the translation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3VCvp.png) even though both source and destination are set as English.  It also only seems to do the name under the main post, rather than that in comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Chrome just translates most pages to English for me. And you can see the rest of the page is in English only my name got changed.

Comment: @AniMenon: Well there you go then :)

Comment: silent automatic page translation. what could possibly go wrong? ©Light

Comment: If Google are doing such a horrible job with translation, I'm dreaded to imagine the day when their cars will start driving autonomously. Those things can't and must not be automated, no matter how many billions of dollars you'll throw on it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think your browser thinks your name is a Romanian phrase and automatically translated it to English with [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?espv=2&biw=1600&bih=799&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.123664746,d.cWw&ion=1&sns=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/en/ani%20menon).

Many languages put certain adjectives after the noun instead of before (like in English). Looking at [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?espv=2&biw=1600&bih=799&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&ion=1&sns=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/ro/fantastic%20years), I see that "fantastic years" becomes "ani fantastic" in Romanian.

If you are in Chrome, you are given the option to automatically translate things. I suggest that you check your browser settings to see if that got enabled somehow. If it automatically translates every non-English language, you should see a lot of not Japanese on this page: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/.

See also: [Why does Chrome incorrectly determine page is in a different language and offer to translate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467454)

Comment: That is a possible answer, but why only the name? Why not the whole page? Also I only use the browser in English.

Comment: @AniMenon As I said, I'm not sure, especially without more info on what you're using. Computers are definitely weird but also amazing. Something incredible about Chrome is that I changed no settings, but the red spell check lines adapt. For example, if I start pinging someone with a long enough Russian name, the next words will have a red line because they are not valid Russian.

Comment: oh.. Yes am using chrome too.

Comment: @AniMenon I found some more info on this (see edits). You should definitely check your settings in Chrome.

Comment: Checked that. It translates all to English.

Comment: @AniMenon You should change it then. Just make it ask you first, otherwise it's annoying and also a possible security threat.

Comment: Yes, but I still am able to understand why only my name changed. Possibly a chrome bug. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @AniMenon My guess is that everything else is already in English (so was your name, but hey...), so the translation would just arrive at the same phrases.

Comment: @Adam ya maybe.

Comment: @Adam: "Ani Menon" is not a valid English phrase, nor does it contain any valid English words. So I find it difficult to see how it was "already in English"!

Comment: Will Google still translate if the page's HTML is specified as English/US? Should SO add a rich snippet ( something like "username" ) to the usernames to indicate they shouldn't be translated?

Comment: @ButtleButkus I assume that they can just follow the steps in the SO post I linked. But I think that usernames should be translated, if it's translating to a language other than English (or the localized language for the localized SO). As someone who uses GT to browse the other SOs, I know it makes it easier to follow \@pings when both are translated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Er, I meant that it was in English as much as my name is or yours or anyone else's if written in the English alphabet. Not that it was composed out of dictionary English words. Bad attempt at making fun of automatic translation on my part.

Answer (score 23):

Yep, This is what happened.. :)

[image: All are correct, this is what happend.. :)]

Comment: That's a very funny issue. I need to write it down in my list of "everything can happen" test cases.

Comment: :) yeah, Everything can happen

Comment: And usually already has...

Answer (score 2):

This is the *Romanian* language!! If you are using google chrome it will automatically translate phrases it picks up are from a different language. You can turn this up by clicking the little 'A' translate button in the top right of the address bar.

*Note that a poster above saw that it had the same word in French, this is because Romanian is a Romance language like French and based on Latin.*

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something weird with chrome, I just got this:

[image]

Chrome somehow thought it would be reasonable to translate a random *.pipe* to *Kabul*. I have no automatic translation activated, and I've never seen this strange behavior before. Is stackoverflow doing something strange that is triggering this obscure behavior in chrome somehow?