# Work location translated to French

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

A while ago, I set up the places I want to work. Today I looked at my profile, and it seems that one entry (Lansing, MI) has the text "États-Unis" next to it. I believe that's French for USA. The other entries look fine:

[image]

Same goes for the preview of my CV.

My Browser is Firefox 47.0 and the header `Accept-Language` is `de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`

Comment: Maybe related problem: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325505/2675154

Comment: I don't think so, the first (Wiesbaden, Deutschland) is in German, the second (Lansing, MI, États-Unis) seems to be French and the third is just USA (might be english or german).

Comment: Just to confirm, that is indeed French for USA

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If so do you have automatic translation enabled somewhere?

Comment: It's a Brexit bug. Everything is switching to French now.

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm using Firefox, but in Chrome it looks the same, automatic translation is disabled. If its enabled, everything is in German, not in French (I don't speak French nor live there, all my PCs are set up either german or english)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi #lmao or #mdr

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Regardless of who's in the E.U., the United States will _never_ switch to French. :)

Comment: @reirab, never say never ;) English is clear, concise and efficient, *mais le français a son charme*.

Comment: There would not BE an independent United States without the French

Comment: Of course the best solution is to start learning french.
You'll find plenty of ressources on internet, not to mention french.stackexchange.com

Comment: You just ate too much French fries :)